# How to prevent connection losing in google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When the user does nothing for a long time (4-5-10 hours maybe) google maps becomes grey. What I need for reload connection?

Like this: [image]

Comment: I have never seen that happening in any app using google maps api v3. If you need help, share your code.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this answer](https://issuetracker.google.com/65212482#comment2) on Google's Public Issue Tracker:

> The Google Maps JavaScript API requires a session token which is obtained during API bootstrap. The 403 errors that you observe are most likely due to the expiration of your Javascript Maps API session: sessions are limited in time, you will have to reload your page if you want to keep displaying a map.
>
> If you are in the situation where you need the app to be present for a long time (e.g wall monitor), you could load the API inside an iframe as a workaround. Then every day you can reload the iframe (and request the JS API), fetch/restore app state through document cross-messaging [1] and re-initialize your mapping services with that state.
>
> [1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage